# addEventListenner on js : the bubble does not want to be canceled

Tags: javascript, html, click, addeventlistener

I coded a game for 2 people:
Initialization is done with player1 ()
with the displayScore () function I can reiterate the score as much as I want (here everything is fine)
but when I switch to the other player with the changePlayer (player) function, the event goes well with player2 I can also reiterate but the concern is that the first player continues to play while my functions and variables are well partitioned
the problem comes from the event of the first which continues despite my stopPropagation () which I did not forget to report.

Where's the problem I've been on for a day and a half.

I join the two files html and js and also css

Thank you in advance,
cordially.

jeu de dés

```
<body>
    <div id="launchGame">
        <h1>NEW GAME</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="players">
        <div id="player_1"><h2>PLAYER 1</h2><span id="score_player_1">Score :</span></div>
        <picture><img id="dice">img</picture>
        <div id="player_2"><h2>PLAYER 2</h2><span id="score_player_2">Score :</span></div>
    </div>

    <div id="current_score">
        <div id="current_score_1"><p>current<span id="round_player_1"></span></p></div>
            <div id="controls_game">
                <h3 id="roll_dice"><img src="images/re_game.png">ROLL DICE</h3>
                <h3 id="hold"><img src="images/charge_score.png">HOLD</h3>
            </div>
        <div id="current_score_2"><p>current<span id="round_player_2"></span></p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
(function(){

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 

    const launch = document.getElementById("launchGame");
    const rollDice = document.getElementById("roll_dice");

    function currentPlayer(player) {

        const hold = document.getElementById("hold");

        if (player.getElementsByTagName("img").length < 1) {
            player.firstChild.style.position = "relative";

            var currentPlayer = new Image();
            currentPlayer.src = "images/current_player.png";
            currentPlayer.setAttribute("class", player.getAttribute("id"));

            currentPlayer.style.position = "absolute";

            player.firstChild.appendChild(currentPlayer);
        }   else {
                player.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
            }

            changePlayer(player);

            rollDice.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            displayScore(player);
            }, {capture:false, once: false, useCapture: true});          
    }

    function player1() {
        let player1 = document.getElementById("player_1");
        currentPlayer(player1);
    }

    function player2() {
        let player2 = document.getElementById("player_2");
        currentPlayer(player2);
    }

    function changePlayer(player) { 
        hold.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            player.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";

            if (player.getAttribute("id") === "player_1") {
                console.log(player.getAttribute("id"));
                player2();
            } else if (player.getAttribute("id") === "player_2") {
                console.log(player.getAttribute("id"));
                player1();
              }
        }, {capture:false, once:true, useCapture: true});
    }

    function displayScore(player) {
            let scoreDice = getScoreDice();
            let scorePlayer = document.getElementById("round_" + 
            player.getAttribute("id")); 
            scorePlayer.textContent = scoreDice(); 
    }

    function getScoreDice() {
        var result = 0;
        var faceDice = Math.floor(Math.random()*7); 
    
        if ((faceDice > 0) && (faceDice < 7)) {
            result = faceDice;
        } else {
            result = faceDice+1;
          }  

        function innerGetScoreDice() {
            return result;
        }

        return innerGetScoreDice;
    }
    
    launch.addEventListener("click", player1(), {capture:false, once:true});

});
})()



    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: silver;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, white, white 50%, rgb(228, 227, 227) 50%, rgb(228, 227, 227));
    text-align: center;
    color: gray;
}

h1 {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1% auto 5%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h1::before {
    content: "⊕ ";
    font-size: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    color: tomato;
}

h2 {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 7% 0;
}

span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50%;
}

img {
    max-width: 10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

#players, #final_score, #current_score, #current_score_1, #current_score_2, #controls_game {
    display: flex;
}

#players, #final_score, #current_score {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
#players {
    justify-content:space-around;
    margin: 1% 1% 10%;
}

#current_score_1, #current_score_2 {
    border-radius: 20%;
    padding: 2% 4%;
    background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
}

#controls_game {
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function changePlayer(player), isn't variable 'hold' undefined ?

Comment: No The variable hold is defined and ok All variables are ok Problems is in event of first players Bubble or capture I don't now whats this

Answer (score 0):

No
The variable hold is defined and ok
All variables are ok
Problems is in event of first players
Bubble or capture
I don't now whats this